# Formato de fecha "dd-MM-yyyy" sin pipe

Tags: javascript, angular

Tengo esa duda necesito grabarlo en una variable con ese formato pero la pipe me parece que solo funciona en el HTML.

Necesito la fecha del día de hoy con el formato  `dd-MM-yyyy`

La fecha de hoy la saco asi

```
this.today = Date.now();
```

Pero ahí me quedo...He estado buscando pero no lo encuentro solo me salen formas utilizando la pipe.

Saludos y gracias

Comment: Moment.js? Has probado usarla? Ya que no quieres usar los Pipes, sino pide tu mismo el día, el mes y el año y has el String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solo debes manejar la fecha de la siguiente forma:

```js
let mi_fecha = new Date()
console.log(`${mi_fecha.getDate()}-${mi_fecha.getMonth() + 1}-${mi_fecha.getFullYear()}` )
```

el único cuidado es que el mes siempre empieza en 0 que es enero

Comment: Gracias veo que la funcion new Date() es de typescript y el de angular es this.today = Date.now(); me ha servido tu solución!

Comment: no es de typescript, es de javascript no he podido editar tu pregunta porque no han aprobado la edicion anterior